# Convert JSONArray to Object?

Tags: simplejson

I have the following JSON and I want to create an Contact object from it. How we can do that using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here is the String

> {"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Contact/0037F000001rW9rQAE"},"Id":"0037F000001rW9rQAE","Name":"Chris Smith"}]}

I developed below code but how how to used JSONArray to get the details from it ?

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(value);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray jsonArray =  (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("records");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~>>> "+jsonArray);


        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject rec = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.setId(jsonArray.get(j).toString());

            contacts.add(jsonArray.get(j).toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your issue like this but if you want to manage exceptions you should use the method getString(KEY), instead optString(KEY)

```
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
   JSONObject rec = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
   Contact c = new Contact();
   c.setId(rec.optString("Id"));
   c.setName(rec.optString("Name"));
   c.setAtributes(rec.optJSONObject("attributes"))
   contacts.add(rec);
}
```